# Apex Webservice returning **Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization:**

Tags: apex, json, rest-service

I have a webservice, and I'm trying to send a List of Apex classes to my SFDC org.  Before I even get anywhere in my POST method Salesforce just returns an error.

Sample JSON:

```
{"FieldParser": {
{"fieldName": "producerCode", "value": ""}, {"fieldname": "description", "value": "otherval"}}
```

Code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/StagingREST/*')
global with sharing class EVantageAccountRest
{
  global List<FieldParser> FieldParser;

  global class FieldParser {
    public String fieldName;
    public String value;
  }

  public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
    return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
  }

  @HttpPost
  global static JSONStatus saveAccount(String jsonString)
  {
    //it doesn't even reach the code in here.
    System.debug('string = ' + jsonString);
    return new JSONStatus(false, 'string = ' + jsonString, null);
  }
}
```

JSON2Apex:

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public List<FieldParser> FieldParser;

    public class FieldParser {
        public String fieldName;
        public String value;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?  For some reason SFDC seems to think this JSON string being passed is bad.

Comment: You appear to have an extra set of `{}` in your JSON, shouldn't it be `{"FieldParser": {
"fieldName": "producerCode", "value": ""}}`? Without seeing your JSON2Apex class it's hard to figure out what Apex is expecting from your JSON.

Comment: @AlexTennant  My bad I simplified it too much.  I believe I need all of those {}  Adjusting JSON.

Comment: Any chance of including the JSON2Apex class too?

Comment: @AlexTennant  I included that class, but currently it's not even being used.  It was one of the many things I tried, so maybe I should have removed the reference to it to begin with.  It doesn't even get to the point where it **tries** to parse the JSON string.

Comment: Hmm. That's very odd. How are you calling the REST service? Workbench, Java, something else?

Comment: @AlexTennant I'm using the Postman chrome plugin.  A coworker was using another tool but I"m not sure what it was.  He's not available to ask atm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you gave the REST method a String parameter, the platform is expecting input of the form

```
{ "jsonString" : "some string" }
```

If you're wanting to pass in a list of `FieldParser` objects, one way to do this is to have the REST method take a list of `FieldParser` as an argument, like this:

```
@HttpPost
global static JSONStatus saveAccount(List<FieldParser> fieldParsers)
```

In this case, you'll need to pass the JSON in the form

```
{ 
  "fieldParsers" : [
    {
      "fieldName": "name1", 
      "value": "value1"
    }, 
    {
      "fieldName": "name2", 
      "value": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

An alternative is to have it take no arguments and get the POST body in the from the request, like this:

```
@HttpPost
global static JSONStatus saveAccount() {
    List<FieldParser> fieldParsers = (List<FieldParser>)JSON.deserialize(
       RestContext.request.requestBody.tostring(), 
       List<FieldParser>.class);
```

This would allow you to directly pass a list of `FieldParser` objects:

```
[
  {
    "fieldName" : "name1".
    "value" : "value1"
  },
  {
    "fieldName" : "name2".
    "value" : "value2"
  }
]
```

Comment: The **List<FieldParser>** parameters didn't work, but using your other way along with the new way to pass the input did.

Comment: Huh - what was the error? It should work; I'd like to figure out why it didn't...

Comment: **[
    {
        "message": "JSON request body must be an object at [line:1, column:2]",
        "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
    }
]**

Comment: Actually, I got the other way to work by making the JSON: **{"fieldParsers": [{"fieldName": "ProducerCode__c", "value": "001"}, {"fieldName": "FirstName__c", "value": "Paul"}]}**

Comment: Ah - that does make sense! I'll edit my answer now - thanks for the update!